# How can we obtain frequency difference of two waveforms?

Tags: frequency, pll, frequency-measurement, instrumentation

Given a reference waveform from the transmit, how can we detect the change in frequency of the resulting transmitted waveform using a PLL (like an LM565). Most resources only discuss about getting the phase difference.

Comment: Becuse PLL is a phase locked loop, so when it is locked has equal phase, which also implies equal frequency. Have you searched for beat frequency oscillator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input to the VCO of a PLL will be related to the frequency of the input when the loop is locked.

For example, the LM565 has a typical VCO sensitivity of 6600Hz/volt when the center frequency is set at 10kHz, so the VCO control input will change by about 150mV/Hz when the loop is locked.

If you have two waveforms you could use two PLLs and subtract the VCO input differences- you'd also have to remove some offset voltage and calibrate the gains, no doubt.

Answer (score 2):

> How can we obtain frequency difference of two waveforms?

This is done in radio receivers when the local oscillator is "mixed" with the broad range of potential stations picked up by the antenna. RF guys call it mixing but basically it's multiplication and is used to position the desired station to the difference frequency. It is then passed through a band pass filter that only selects a small band around this difference frequency. RF guys call it the intermediate frequency or I.F. Retuning the local oscillator will select a different desired station hence a single set of fixed frequency filters are used to reject everything that is unwanted.

So, multiplying two signals generates an exact difference frequency. It also generates a frequency that is the sum of the two frequencies so some care has to be taken i.e. it will work providing that the sum frequency can be eradicated.

For instance if the difference frequency is 3 kHz from signals at 2 kHz and 5 kHz, the sum will be 7 kHz. However a sum frequency of 3 kHz can be made from 1 kHz and 2 kHz so that's what you need to watch out for.

It all comes down to what range of frequencies you are wanting this to work for.